# configuring an existing application written in C++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, architecture, xml-parsing

First of all, this is a design question rather than an issue:

I have an existing application written in C++.

The structure is as following:

```
class Step1
{
    public:
      Step1();
      void process();
      void setValue(int v); // is to change the value
    private:
      int value;
}

class Step2
{
    public:
      Step2();
      void process();
      void setValue(int v); // is to change the value
    private:
      int value;
}

void main()
{
    Step1 step1();
    Step2 step2();

    step1.setValue(1);
    step2.setValue(2);

    step1.process();
    step2.process();
}
```

I am now allowed to change the current architecture but it is required to configure all of the steps from outside. I am proposing to create an xml file holding the configuration settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Steps>
   <Step id="step1">
      <param method="setValue" variable="v" value="1" />
   </Step>
   <Step id="step2">
      <param method="setValue" variable="v" value="2" />
   </Step>
</Steps>
```

And then I will add a class to parse the xml file:

class XmlParser
{
    public:
      XmlParser();
      int parse(string xmlFile, string paramValue);
}

then I think I will change the main class only:

```
void main()
{
    Step1 step1();
    Step2 step2();

    XmlParser xmlParser();

    step1.setValue(xmlParser.parse(,));
    step2.setValue(xmlParser.parse(,));

    step1.process();
    step2.process();
}
```

I have more than 20 steps and there are about 10 methods to be configured in every step. Is it a good idea to change the architecture in this way that the XmlParser class will parse the xml file and pass the values to the set methods of the steps. Or is there a better way to do this?

I would like to know your opinions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The xml makes your code more configurable in the sense that the data resides separate from the code,However it adds a little overhead of parsing the xml.So it depends what is your primary aim for modification of the design.

Comment: My aim is to make the application configurable from the outside. Therefore, I introduced the xml to hold the configuration settings and add the xmlParser class. Yes, I agree with you that the parse() method of the xmlParser will be very over complicated and not easy to read. What would you suggest? thanks in advance.

Comment: If the aim is to make your application externally configurable then using the xml is a good idea, Encapsulating the xml parsing in a separate class is a good idea as well, I may also suggest using some good open source xml parsing library for ease of usage and coding.You have the right approach, All the best.

Comment: thanks @Als, yes I will use an open source xml parsing library.

Comment: Use constructor injection of the values if possible. Also you could use a Factory which takes the xml path extracts every neccessary value and constructs an object with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already faced this problem and I have done something similar. I think it's the most reasonable solution. For creation and setting of an instance of your processing classes (Steps, in your example) should be responsible your main subroutine/class.

One problem is parsing XML, you might change your current source code into the mess. To prevent that, you should create some class "Configuration", that is responsible for parsing, error handling and default values of your settings.

Simple example of Configuration class interface:

```
class Configuration {
public:
    // basic configuration
    Configuration();
    // parsing, DTD validation
    void parse(const std::string& filename);
    // get some value
    // you can provide default value if necessary
    // or you can have some more robust accessing methods
    // depends on complexity of your settings
    int getSomeValue(int default);
    ...
};
```

Main subroutine is not filled with parsing stuff:

```
void main()
{
    Configuration config;
    config.parse("path/to/config.xml");

    Step1 step1();
    Step2 step2();

    int someValue = config.getValue(5);
    step1.setSomeValue(someValue);
    ...

    step1.process();
    step2.process();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

If you decide to pass the `XmlParser` to Step objects, then your example will look like this :

```
int main()
{
    XmlParser xmlParser();

    Step1 step1( xmlParser );
    Step2 step2( xmlParser );


    step1.setValue();
    step2.setValue();

    step1.process();
    step2.process();
}
```

This is good, because you can pass mock objects to the step objects in your unit tests.

Comment: thanks @VJovic. But with this approach, I will then have to modify the constructor of the steps or introduce subclass for the existing step classes. Is it right? I wonder how you do the setValue() method.

Comment: @devn Yes, modify the constructor instead of the setValue method. Inside setValue, parse the xml file and set values.